# AutoCompleteTextView suggestion list is always delayed by ONE character, why?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I am having a really hard time figuring out the following problem or bug or whatever it is. I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` and every single time the user enters a character, a http request is called for downloading the suggestions from an external database. This part works fine, the threshold is 3 characters so if the user enters "ma", the drop down list does not show, then writing "mak" I can clearly see that the http request is called and in the log "make cake", "make whatever" etc show up. 
The issue is related to the `AutoCompleteTextView` as the drop down is somehow delayed with one character.

The very first time I write "mal" no drop down list shows up (there is malter in the external db, which shows up correctly in the log) , then I remove the text and write "pum", the "pump" shows up in the log, but the "malter" comes up in drop down list. Then if I write "puml", "pump" shows up in the drop down list, which was supposed to be shown up 1 character before.

This is the Asynctask - note that the request works correct, as I mentioned before, the Log brings up the correct suggestions, there might be a problem setting the adapter etc (i guess..).

**SuggestAsyncTask:**

```
 private class SuggestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
              //Logging the elements of array_goals_name is also OK.             
              adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewGoalsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_goals_name);
              actv_name.setAdapter(adapter);

          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() { }

          @Override
          protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

              try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = null;
                    httppost = new HttpPost(search_goal);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newtext", params[0]));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("error", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    }
                    //convert response to string
                    try{
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            is.close();
                            //Log.i("sb", sb + "");
                            Bresult=sb.toString();
                            //Log.i("Bresult", Bresult + "");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("error", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    }

                    array_goals_name.clear();

                    try {
                        if (Bresult != null) {
                            jArray = new JSONArray(Bresult);
                            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                                for(int j=0;j<innerJsonArray.length();j++){  
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                    array_goals_name.add(jsonObject.getString("NAME"));
                                    Log.d("NAME: ", "" + jsonObject.getString("NAME")));  
           //this works fine! When the 3rd character is pushed the log output is correct, etc

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return null;

          }

      }
```

You can see that in the onPostExecute() I always set the new adapter after `array_goals_name` `ArrayList` and I expect it showing with the suggestions contained in this `ArrayList`. I did not include here, but logging the elements of this ArrayList array_goals_name is also ok (getting the correct suggestions but no dropdown list).

**part of OnCreate:**

```
array_goals_name = new ArrayList<String>();
actv_name = (NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_name);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewBucketActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_goals_name);
actv_name.setWillNotCacheDrawing(true);

actv_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (actv_name.isPerformingCompletion()) {
                        // An item has been selected from the list. Ignore.
                        return;
                   } else {
                       if (actv_name.getText().toString().length() > 2) {
                            new SuggestAsyncTask().execute(actv_name.getText().toString());
                            }
                   }           
              }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  }

          });
```

I also created the NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView class to make a custom AutoCompleteTextView as it was suggested if there was any problem filtering (ignoring) the spacebar. This part of code is a scheme.
**NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView:**

```
public class NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

   public NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   // this is how to disable AutoCompleteTextView filter
   @Override
   protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
       String filterText = "";
       super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
   }
}
```

What might be the problem?

**--------- EDIT -----------------**

```
    actv_name = (NewBucketCustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_name);
    actv_name.setThreshold(3);
    String[] from = { "name" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
    actv_name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.otf"));
    SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, from, to, 0);
    a.setStringConversionColumn(1);

        FilterQueryProvider provider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                // run in the background thread
                Log.d("TAG", "runQuery constraint: " + constraint);
                if (constraint == null) {
                    return null;
                }


                try {

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = null;
                    httppost = new HttpPost(search_goal);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newtext", constraint.toString()));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("error", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    }
                    //convert response to string
                    try{
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            is.close();
                            //Log.i("sb", sb + "");
                            Bresult=sb.toString();
                            //Log.i("Bresult", Bresult + "");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("error", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    }

                    String[] columnNames = { "_id" , "name" };
                MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);

                    try {
                        if (Bresult != null) {
                            jArray = new JSONArray(Bresult);
                            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                                for(int j=0;j<innerJsonArray.length();j++){  
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                    array_goals_name.add(jsonObject.getString("NAME"));
                                    Log.d("NAME", "" + jsonObject.getString("NAME"));
                                    c.newRow().add(j).add(jsonObject.getString("NAME"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                return c;
            }
        };
        a.setFilterQueryProvider(provider);
        actv_name.setAdapter(a);
```

Comment: Ok I got back to the original ACTV and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem but I use the default AutoCompleTextView. Any ideas? What I can say for sure is that this delay happens when you are populating the Adapter from somwhere else than the local in-app-data (like XML data or something). I have the same ACTV in one app where it works, but I read the data from predefined classes there. When I fetch the data from somewhere else in another app with the same implementation (I fetch it from a REST service, as you do it from database), this problem occurs.